# Searching for opcode bytes in PE file

Tags: c, portable-executable, opcode

I have a task of searching for opcode bytes in a PE file and checking whether a specified opcode byte sequence (constant and predefined) is present in the PE file. I have come across numerous examples online, but the solutions are mostly in C# or Python; however, my requirements are based in C language.

Please tell me how can I check and compare opcode byte values in a PE file by writing a simple program in C. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What are your efforts so far?

Comment: I have implemented a PE parser program that shows details about all sections available. But I'm unclear as to how can I look for a sequence of bytes in the executable sections?

Comment: Consider `string.h` and the functions in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may take a look at [ROPGadget](https://github.com/JonathanSalwan/ROPgadget/) or at [rp](https://github.com/0vercl0k/rp), both software contain code that do what you want (and more).